# How to costumize the input fields but only in the page /user?

Tags: 7, theming

I want to create a particular style with css for input style in the field of login, register and request new password.
The css if i see it width firebug is only one and i must adding a type only for the form of the /user page, but not for all page that containes form.
Thank you for help!

Comment: You should review your questions and mark the answers that solved your question as the accepted answer. This is done by clicking the big check button next to the voting widget. Doing so adwards the one that spent his time answering your question with a little rep, but more importantly is helps other people with the same problem to quickly see what solution helped you. Sometimes there are no answers that solves your question, but I find it hard to believe this is the case for **ALL** your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the classes added to the opening body tag in the HTML. It will help you narrow down styles to just that page.

I know one of my D6 sites, there is a class in the body tag 'page-user' so you can use some CSS such as...

```
body.page-user .form-text {
  /* Add styling */
}
```

Inspect the HTML and style as necessary. :o)